# How to implement a javascript API using JSNI?

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am trying to implement an API (SCORM API) using GWT. 
The client code expects an API object with methods like Initialize(), getLastError() and so on...

I tried to implement this api as an Java Object, but i see that the compiled names are changed and cannot be used directly by client code.

I see that gwt-exporter can do the trick (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) but i would like to know how to do it using pure gwt and jsni.

As the API is expected as a object, named API_1484_11 attached to the window object, not an function, , i  don't see how to use the $entry() idiom.

Here is my current, failing, code:

```
public final class SCORMApi {

    protected SCORMApi() {}

    public void Initialize(){
        GWT.log("** INITIALIZE CALLED **");
    }

    public static void create(){
        bind(new SCORMApi());
    }

    public static native void bind(SCORMApi api) /*-{
        $wnd.API_1484_11 = api;
    }-*/;

}
```

So, in this context, my question is:

How can i get javascript calls (e.g. `window.API_1484_11.Initialize()` ) to reach my java gwt code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right lines with your `bind` method.  But you haven't understood how to call Java methods from within JSNI.  This is how you do it in the case of your Initialize method:

```
public static native void bind(SCORMApi api) /*-{
    $wnd.API_1484_11 = {
        initialize: function() {
            $entry( api.@com.yourpackage.name.SCORMApi::Initialize()() );
        }
    };
}-*/;
```

The blogs Getting To Really Know GWT parts [1](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html) and [2](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html) are required reading on this subject.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I am actually using something like this but was trying not to write the api twice (once in the javascript inline object and once in java). But i guess that is as good as it gets...

Comment: On my code i have not used the $entry, as did the part 1 of the article you mentioned ("Creating JavaScript libraries with GWT" part), and it seems to work all right. The docs are quite vague on the workings of $entry, would you know where to find more about it?

Comment: Do consider using GWT Exporter, I use it extensively exactly for this purpose.